# How to write SQL statements in php?

Tags: php, sql

I was getting started in SQL but i don't know how to write the SQL statements in php. So how to write SQL statements in PHP language? I use the Access database program

Comment: Your question is not really clear what do you mean how? SQL statements are everywhere the same. Do you mean how you connect and get data from a database with php?

Comment: maybe add some extra info...

Comment: I saw this code: `var result =
db.query("select * from T");
` Maybe that will help me.

Comment: That will basically be a query that SELECT every column FROM that particular TABLE (i've used caps as its good practice when writing SQL queries)

Comment: Then i put `var result = db.query();` and use `document.getElementaryById();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM students
```

very simply but is a query to select all rows from a table called 'students'

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel.
2. Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
3. Choose the System DSN tab.
4. Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
5. Select the Microsoft Access Driver. Click Finish.
6. In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
7. Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
8. Click OK.

and use below code to fetch

**Connecting to an ODBC**

```
$conn=odbc_connect('northwind','','');
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

**Retrieving Records**

```
odbc_result($rs,1); 
odbc_fetch_row($rs)
```

Use this link from [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp)
good Luck

Comment: This is for SQL Server, not MS Access.

Comment: edited answer pls check!

Comment: Ok i will not use SQL anymore. I will just use HTML markup for making tables

Comment: i cant understand you want fetch `query` from access to php ok?

Comment: @jakobaindreas11 You haven't even understood what the difference between database table and HTML table is? Please find out before you do anything in PHP, it is a very basic concept!

Comment: wait you want set value & run sql statment to access from php??Your question is not really clear what do you mean how pls check it! if you want to set your sql query test above code pls dear alex!! and look your question vote

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql)

Here's a great tutorial showing you how to and why to use it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

Create an ODBC Connection. With an ODBC connection, you can connect to any database, on any computer in your network, as long as an ODBC connection is available.

Here is how to create an ODBC connection to a MS Access Database:

1. Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel.
2. Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
3. Choose the System DSN tab.
4. Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
5. Select the Microsoft Access Driver. Click Finish.
6. In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
7. Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
8. Click OK.

Note that this configuration has to be done on the computer where your web site is located. If you are running Internet Information Server (IIS) on your own computer, the instructions above will work, but if your web site is located on a remote server, you have to have physical access to that server, or ask your web host to to set up a DSN for you to use.

```
<html>
    <body>

<?php
    $conn=odbc_connect('northwind','','');
    if (!$conn)
      {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
    $sql="SELECT * FROM customers";
    $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    if (!$rs)
      {exit("Error in SQL");}
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo "<th>Companyname</th>";
    echo "<th>Contactname</th></tr>";
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
      {
      $compname=odbc_result($rs,"CompanyName");
      $conname=odbc_result($rs,"ContactName");
      echo "<tr><td>$compname</td>";
      echo "<td>$conname</td></tr>";
      }
    odbc_close($conn);
    echo "</table>";
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use an IDE with a VM on it

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify what you already tried.

First, one would have a look at whether "Access database program" is in the list of databases supported by PHP at https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php

WHich is not the case. Because of that, you would go with an abstraction layer:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.abstract.php

Everything is in the docs, except for whether Access supports any of these abstraction layers. Please look at the MSDN docs regarding abstraction layers supported by Access. I would try ODBC first, at least back in my times it was the DBAL most widely available...

Comment: I meant the MS Access database program

Answer (score 0):

You can use php/mssql extensions . Please check the php manual below.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

i think it will help you 

    ";

```
    $db_databaseName="dbsocial";

    function selectdb()
    {
        require_once "dataBase.php";
        global $db_databaseName;

        $db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostName,$db_userName,$db_password);

        if(!$db_server)
        {
            die("could not with server ".mysql_error());
            echo "connect to Server"."<br />";
        }

        mysql_select_db($db_databaseName);
        if(!$db_databaseName)
        {
            die("Could not connect with Data Base .".mysql_error());
            echo "Connect to Database"."<br />";
        }
    }
    selectdb();

    function insertValue()
    {

        $userName = $_POST['userName'];
        $sqlloginExist="select * from  `user` where (`user_name`='".$userName."') ";
        $queryLogin=mysql_query($sqlloginExist);
        $resultExistUserName=mysql_fetch_array($queryLogin); 



        if($resultExistUserName>1)
        {
            echo "User Name or Email Exist"."<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql="INSERT into user (user_name,password,age,gender) VALUES ('".$_POST['userName']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['gender']."')";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            $sqlDivision="insert into division (division_name) VALUES ('".$_POST['division']."')";
            $resultDivision=mysql_query($sqlDivision);
            echo "ok1" ."<br />";

            $sqlDistric="insert into district(district_name) VALUES('".$_POST['district']."')";
            echo "ok2"."<br />";
            $resultDistric=mysql_query($sqlDistric);

            $adress = htmlentities($_POST['address']);  
            echo $adress;
            //echo $_POST['address'];
            $sqlAddress="insert into `address`(postal_code,address_detail) values ('".$_POST['postalCode']."','".$adress."')";
            $resultAddress=mysql_query($sqlAddress);
            echo "ok3"."<br />";
            //echo "Address insert";

            if(!$result && !$resultDivision && !$resultDistric && !$resultAddress)
            {
                die("Insertion falied" .mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                echo "successfull inserttion";
            }
        }
    }
    insertValue();
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is Access code.

Comment: he want to access database using SQL in php .so i am gave the all procudure how to select localhost,database, insert data into table .if i am not worng it will help the user .from this point of view i gave it

Comment: "I use the Access database program". To me this means MS Access....

Comment: Steve you are most senior then me you batter then me :) . ijust point this user asked this SQL statements in php?